# Can not import class from module in another file

Tags: python, module

There is a class with the name of PlanarTransform in transforms.py

```
class PlanarTransform(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim=20):
        super().__init__()
        self.u = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, dim) * 0.01)
        self.w = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, dim) * 0.01)
        self.b = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(()) * 0.01)
    def m(self, x):
        return -1 + torch.log(1 + torch.exp(x))
    def h(self, x):
        return torch.tanh(x)
    def h_prime(self, x):
        return 1 - torch.tanh(x) ** 2
    def forward(self, z, logdet=False):
        # z.size() = batch x dim
        u_dot_w = (self.u @ self.w.t()).view(())
        w_hat = self.w / torch.norm(self.w, p=2) # Unit vector in the direction of w
        u_hat = (self.m(u_dot_w) - u_dot_w) * (w_hat) + self.u # 1 x dim
        affine = z @ self.w.t() + self.b
        z_next = z + u_hat * self.h(affine) # batch x dim
        if logdet:
            psi = self.h_prime(affine) * self.w # batch x dim
            LDJ = -torch.log(torch.abs(psi @ u_hat.t() + 1) + 1e-8) # batch x 1
            return z_next, LDJ
        return z_next
```

I want to import this class in another python file named flows.py

```
from transforms import *


class PlanarFlow(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim=20, F=16):
        super().__init__()
        self.transforms = nn.ModuleList([PlanarTransform(dim) for f in range(F)])
    def forward(self, z, logdet=False):
        zK = z
        SLDJ = 0.
        for transform in self.transforms:
            out = transform(zK, logdet=logdet)
            if logdet:
                SLDJ += out[1]
                zK = out[0]
            else:
                zK = out
                
        if logdet:
            return zK, SLDJ
        return zK
```

but I got the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flows.py", line 28, in <module>
    planar = PlanarFlow(dim=5, F=4)
  File "flows.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.transforms = nn.ModuleList([PlanarTransform(dim) for f in range(F)])
  File "flows.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
    self.transforms = nn.ModuleList([PlanarTransform(dim) for f in range(F)])
NameError: name 'PlanarTransform' is not defined
```

I've searched about it and tried different suggestions but still, I get the same error

Comment: You may be importing from a different module with the same name "transforms", does this output the location you expect `import transforms; print(transforms.__file__)`?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes both files are in the same location